# How to handle forward slash(/) in java jdbc while querying for a particular value?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Below is my query which is successfully working in command window but in JDBC I am unable to get the result set for this.

```
select * From Elp_Dealer_Recon_Wrk where CERTIFICATE='FACTURA MTY10745/24';
```

The same query if I use in cmd window it will return the result set and in jdbc its not returning any result set

Instead of FACTURA MTY10745/24 if I am giving some other value in the table its fetching the records in jdbc.

Can anyone help me on this please

Comment: [Prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: Which database system are you using, and which driver? I am not aware of systems where the forward slash has special significance.

Comment: I am using oracle Database @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@OrangeDog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611046/how-to-handle-forward-slash-in-java-jdbc-while-querying-for-a-particular-valu/45611361#comment78180492_45611046) mention in comment, to avoid such errors you have to use `PreparedStatement`, here is an example you can follow :

```
String str = "FACTURA MTY10745/24";
String query = "Select DATE_COMP From ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK WHERE CERTIFICATE = ?";
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
try(PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)){
    pst.setString(1, str);// Set the input
    ResultSet result = pst.executeQuery();
    //... get results
}
```